# MPI Send and Receive don't work with more then 8182 double

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm having some troubles with the following code:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int id, p, n, ln, i, j, retCode;
double *buffer;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);


n = strtol(argv[1],NULL,10); // total number of elements to be distributed

ln = n/p;   // local number of elements

buffer = (double*)calloc(ln, sizeof(double));

if (id == p-1)  // Process p-1 send to other processes
{
    for (i=0; i< p-1; i++)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Process %d is sending %d elements to process %d\n", p-1, ln, i);
        retCode = MPI_Ssend (buffer, ln, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        if(retCode)
            fprintf(stdout, "MPISend error at file %s, line %d  code %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, retCode);

        fprintf(stdout, "Process %d completed sending to process %d\n", p-1, i);

    }

} 
else    // other processes receive from process p-1
{
    fprintf(stdout, "Process %d is receiving %d elements from process %d\n", id, ln,p-1);
    retCode = MPI_Recv (buffer, ln, MPI_DOUBLE, p-1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    if(retCode)
        fprintf(stdout, "MPI_Recv error at file %s, line %d  code %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, retCode);
    fprintf(stdout, "Process %d received from process %d\n", id, p-1);
}
free(buffer);
MPI_Finalize(); 
return 0;
}
```

The idea is to open a dataset with process p-1 and then to distribute it to the remaining processes. This solution works when the variable ln (local number of elements) is less than 8182. When I increase the number of elements I've the following error:

```
    mpiexec -np 2   ./sendreceive 16366
    Process 0 is receiving 8183 elements from process 1
    Process 1 is sending 8183 elements to process 0
    Fatal error in MPI_Recv: Other MPI error, error stack:
    MPI_Recv(224)...................: MPI_Recv(buf=0x2000590, count=8183,         MPI_DOUBLE, src=1, tag=MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status=0x1) failed
    PMPIDI_CH3I_Progress(623).......: fail failed
    pkt_RTS_handler(317)............: fail failed
    do_cts(662).....................: fail failed
    MPID_nem_lmt_dcp_start_recv(288): fail failed
    dcp_recv(154)...................: Internal MPI error!  cannot read from remote process
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have not called MPI_Finalize() before exiting the program. If I run your code on my laptop I get an error (a different one!) even for small values of "n", which goes away if I call MPI_Finalize() before return.

I would guess that the reason you are *not* getting an error for n <= 8192 is that, somewhere deep inside, MPI is using a different protocol for exchanging messages of 64K bytes or less compared to messages greater than 64K. For the smaller messages, you are just being lucky that the sends complete correctly without calling Finalize().

Comment: Thank you David. I fixed the code, but my problem is not in MPI_Finalize(), in the original code I've it. I run the code also with your fix and I've still the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the code works if you use MPI_Send instead of MPI_Ssend? 
Does it work if you try to use another communication device?

If the answer is yes to at least one of these questions then I would try to check if this is a known bug of the MPI implementation you use.

Comment: As you suggested the problem is in the MPI implementation I'm using.

Comment: Would you be so kind to mark your question as answered?